# Why do I need a "source replication instance" when replicating to CloudSQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When replicating from an external (on-prem) postgres database to CloudSQL, the documentation says I need to create a "source replication instance" in addition to the actual target database.

I don't understand *why* I need this. **What advantage does this give me over setting up a subscription on the target?**

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/configure-replication-from-external#setup-source-instance

I don't understand why I can't run the standard postgres native replication `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION` on the target. Is this related to networking?